# With FParsec is it possible to manipulate the error position when a parser fails?

Tags: parsing, f#, parser-combinators, fparsec

As an example, I will take this [simple C# parser](http://fssnip.net/lf) by Phillip Trelford. In order to parse an identifier he writes this (slightly changed):

```
let reserved = ["for";"do"; "while";"if";"switch";"case";"default";"break" (*;...*)]
let pidentifierraw =
    let isIdentifierFirstChar c = isLetter c || c = '_'
    let isIdentifierChar c = isLetter c || isDigit c || c = '_'
    many1Satisfy2L isIdentifierFirstChar isIdentifierChar "identifier"
let pidentifier =
    pidentifierraw
    >>= fun s ->
        if reserved |> List.exists ((=) s) then fail "keyword instead of identifier"
        else preturn s
```

The problem with pidentifier is that when it fails, the position indicator is at the end of the stream. An example of mine:

```
Error in Ln: 156 Col: 41 (UTF16-Col: 34)
        Block "main" 116x60 font=default fg=textForeground
                                        ^
Note: The column count assumes a tab stop distance of 8 chars.
keyword instead of identifier
```

Obviously, not a C# snippet, but for the example's sake, I've used the `pidentifier` to parse the text after `font=`. Is it possible to tell FParsec to show the error at the beginning of the parsed input? Using `>>?`, `.>>.?` or any of the backtracking variants seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is [`attempt p`](https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.attempt), which will backtrack to the original parser state if parser `p` fails. So you could just define `pidentifier` as:

```ml
let pidentifier =
    pidentifierraw
    >>= fun s ->
        if reserved |> List.exists ((=) s) then fail "keyword instead of identifier"
        else preturn s
    |> attempt   // rollback on failure
```

Output is then something like:

```
Failure:
Error in Ln: 1 Col: 1
default
^

The parser backtracked after:
  Error in Ln: 1 Col: 8
  default
         ^
  Note: The error occurred at the end of the input stream.
  keyword instead of identifier
```

---

### Update

If you don't want to see the backtracking info in the error message, you can use a simplified version of `attempt`, like this:

```ml
let attempt (parser : Parser<_, _>) : Parser<_, _> =
    fun stream ->
        let mutable state = CharStreamState(stream)
        let reply = parser stream
        if reply.Status <> Ok then
            stream.BacktrackTo(&state)
        reply
```

Output is now just:

```
Failure:
Error in Ln: 1 Col: 1
default
^
keyword instead of identifier
```

Comment: I'm surprised to hear that. It works correctly for me. I've updated my answer with the output that I see.

Comment: Yes, I think `>>=?` is effectively `>>=` plus `attempt`. Personally, I always use `attempt`, because it's more general and easier to remember. (FWIW, I also use the `parse` computation builder instead of manually writing binds with `>>=`.)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a simplified version of `attempt` that doesn't include backtracking info in the output error message.

Comment: Yeap that's it. I awarded the answer to you -it was yours anyway, _you_ gave my brain the food to  start thinking :). I think that similarly I can change `>>=?` which is less verbose. PS I will remove my old comments at some point as they don't serve a purpose anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I missed the [`>>=?`](https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.:62::62::61::63:) operator which apparently is (at least semantically) equivalent to `attempt` that [Brian Berns correctly suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71683704/1303323).

The problem with both of these approaches is the subsequent messages `The parser backtracked after:[…]` that can cascade if the preceding parsers are backtracking as well:

```
Error in Ln: 156 Col: 29 (UTF16-Col: 22)
        Block "main" 116x60 font=default fg=textForeground
                            ^
Note: The column count assumes a tab stop distance of 8 chars.
Expecting: space/tab

The parser backtracked after:
  Error in Ln: 156 Col: 42 (UTF16-Col: 35)
          Block "main" 116x60 font=default fg=textForeground
                                           ^
  Note: The column count assumes a tab stop distance of 8 chars.
  Expecting: space/tab
  Other error messages:
    keyword instead of identifier
```

Comment: Yeah, the backtracking info can be a be much in the error message. Unfortunately, I don't think there's an easy way to remove it.